# HP DL380g6 server with graphic card powered by external psu

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I have an old HP dl380 g6 server and I need to use it for renderings but I have one problem, some of servers don't have 6/8 pin power outs for graphic cards, mine don't have it too.

With that in mind I bought a saphire 5450 low profile (no power pins) just for high quality remote and openGL required apps. But the 5450 didn't make it a week, I send I for warranty and if new replacement have same problem I'm in a big trouble.

Here is problem - I have to buy a new graphic card gtx 650 this card have 6pin power pin my concern is the power supply for this card.

My plan is to buy a 250-350w psu but how sync the server boot and external psu start ups. In pc you can short the psu from the motherboard in servers I don't know how to do it?

So guys if any body have knowledge in this area please help.

I find an empty 10pin power out on servers MB for hot plug hards and raid controler. Is that possible tho get power from that for graphic card.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would not start to mess with powersupply cabling. I have done it and been fine, but it was a modular PSU and fortunately, Corsair sent me spares.

Desktop graphics cards are built for short-ish bursts of high usage. Running one in a server which is built for 24/7 usage is a bad idea.
I would look at getting a professional graphics card, such as an AMD Fire Pro line card. These are designed more for heavy, long term workloads.

Regarding using the 10pin, I could not find a reference to it in the HP manuals for the server. I don't fancy cracking open the 2 at work to find it either!

As it is a desktop PSU that you would be looking to use, you could always connect the wires that signal the PSU should spin up to a SPST switch and throw that just before booting the server. It is not ideal but neither is starting to "hotwire" server grade hardware.

Comment: thankyou for respond - to confirm the hotwire part before i boot the server plug the external psu for graphic first. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

HP can supply a 10pin Molex MiniFitJnr to 6pin MFJ cable for GPU use in a G6, it is a standard item, ask your HP vendor, I would say build one your self (£5 in parts) but just get the proper thing for the job.

The HP cables uses a 7 wire topology to the 6 pin so I guess it does V sense thing, best leave that alone for DIY use.